# Get information of multipage tiff image (I;16) with python

Tags: python, tiff, multipage

I am working with images from a multispectral camera and after doing some processing I have 16 bits multipage image with 6 bands in tiff format. Now, I need to get information of each layer through python code, so I used:

```
from __future__ import division   
from PIL import Image             
import numpy as np                
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

files = os.listdir('my directory')
for file in files:
I = Image.open(os.path.join('my directory', "image.tif"))

plt.imshow(np.asarray(I))

plt.show()

print (I.size, I.mode, I.format)

band1 = np.asarray(I,dtype=np.uint16)
A = np.asarray(I,dtype=np.float32)
```

I can read the image but I cannot find the information of the six different layers and actually, I am not sure from which band the values of "A" are. The image is too big to upload it, but I can try to share it if it´s necessary. Thanks.